# NullPointerException while connecting to IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am new to use IBM websphere MQ and downloaded the trial version. v7.5. I am running my client application independently by using some jars which I used after installing IBMMQCLient rpm.
Jars I am including :

- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- dhbcore.jar

I am facing an issue while starting the connection with the queueManager.

Code:

```
    JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);

    JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
    cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
    cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "TestManager");

    **connection = cf.createConnection();**
```

I am getting below NPE with FFST details :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6890)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6277)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6233)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6262)
    at performance.IBMTestProducer.start(IBMTestProducer.java:155)
    at performance.IBMTestProducer.main(IBMTestProducer.java:219)
```

Let me know if I need to add any more jars or what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

> com.ibm.mqjms.jar , com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar, dhbcore.jar

I think you are missing MQ JAR files and you probably don't need 'dhbcore.jar'.  For a regular MQ/JMS application (using MQ v7.5), here are the MQ JAR files that should be in your CLASSPATH:

- com.ibm.mq.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
- connector.jar
- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- fscontext.jar
- jms.jar
- jndi.jar
- jta.jar
- providerutil.jar